# using a variable in $_POST in php?

Tags: php

i have a page in which i am using a dropdown menu. i have passed a variable in the name field of the select tag whose value comes from an array.

```
$query1="Select SSAP from project where projname='$project'";

 $result=mysql_query($query1);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
$ssap = $row['SSAP'];
$query2="Select * from student where SSAP='$ssap'";
$res=mysql_query($query2);
$row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$name=$row1['name'];
echo $name; ?> <select name="<?php echo $name;?>">
                 <option value="A"> Exceptional </option>
                 <option value="B"> Highly Effective </option>
                 <option value="C"> Effective </option>
                 <option value="D"> Good </option>
                 <option value="E"> Not Satisfactory </option>
                 </select> <br> <?php

  }
```

and i need to retrive the value of each select tag created in another variable on the action page.

```
$grade=$_POST[$name];

echo $grade;
```

the first code snippet works fine but i am unable to fetch the value in the second snippet.

Comment: You have a SQL injection on your first line of code and $query2 contains one aswell. And also XSS by echoing the $name.

Comment: Both SQL queries here have SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) that has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) from PHP. You should select a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You are probably **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: you have pass the name in hidden field because you got $name from previous page and you now submit its post value re setted so you have to add <input type="hidden" name="<?php $_POST['name'] ?>" > like this to post a name again to your future action page

Comment: Can you post the result of  var_dump($_POST); on your action script?

Answer (score 0):

When the form containing the `<select>` with the dynamic name is submitted, it is a *different request*, so `$name` hasn't been set.

Answer (score 0):

When your form is submitted, the `<select>` names are getting evaluated like `<select name="Raj">, <select name="Kiran">, ..........<select name="Sameer">` etc depending on the values of `$name=$row1['name'];` from your query on 'student' table.  Also you should pay consideration to the fact that your query `$query2="Select * from student where SSAP='$ssap'";` might return more than one rows, it seems you are assuming only one row will be returned.

> Also note `$_POST` is an associative array that accept parameters as
>   `KEY=>VALUE` pairs from submission of HTML.  In `$_POST` key is name of
>   element in input form value is value of that element in input form

So you can not use a variable as the `KEY` in your `SUPER GLOBAL $POST` like this `$_POST[$name];` when `$name` is undefined on your action script.  I would suggest  you use an named array in your multiple `<Select>`. Do a `var_dump($_POST)` on your action script. That may reveal most of the stuffs for you.